# On click button, alert text tag a (jquery)

Tags: html, button, parent

```
<div class="postContent">
<div class="postMeta">
        <a class="comentsQty">
        <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
        <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
        </a>
</div>
<a href="#" class="postOverlayBtn"></a>
</div>
```

I need to get 1252 on click button .postOverlayBtn
My Jquery don't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(event) {
      alert($(this).prev().find('a.comments_number').text());
});
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/1z5jfjc5/, although the HTML looks invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming corrected HTML:

```
<div class="postContent">
    <div class="postMeta">
        <a class="comentsQty">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
        </a>
        <!-- an interactive element, such as an anchor, cannot be nested inside
             another interactive element -->
        <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="postOverlayBtn">post-overlay-button</a>
</div>
```

Then I'd suggest:

```
// binding a click-handling anonymous function to '.postOverlayBtn' elements:
$('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(){
    // logging to the console:
    console.log($(this)
        // finding the ancestor '.postContent' element:
        .closest('.postContent')
        // finding the descendant '.comments_number' elements:
        .find('.comments_number')
        // returning the text of the (first) '.comments_number' element:
        .text());
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/v0ujgos9/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like that:

```
$('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(event) {
    alert($(this).prev().children(".comments_number").text());
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/at68egcc/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="postContent">
    <div class="postMeta">
        <a class="comentsQty"> <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
        </a>
        <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
        </div>
    </div> 

$jq(document).ready(function() {
     $jq('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(event) {
       alert (console.log($jq(this).closest('.postContent').find('.comments_number').text()));
     })
})
```

alert undefined (((((

```
alert($(this).prev().children(".comments_number").text());
```

alert none (((((

```
<div class="postContent">
    <div class="postMeta">
            <a class="comentsQty">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
            <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
            </a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="postOverlayBtn">click</a>
    </div> 

$jq(document).ready(function() {
   $jq('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(event) {
    alert($jq(this).prev().find('a.comments_number').text());
   })
})
```

alert none

http://jsfiddle.net/r1xj2gvn/3/ it's my test

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="postContent">
<div class="postMeta">
        <a class="comentsQty">
        <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
        <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
        </a>
<div>
    <a href="#" class="postOverlayBtn"></a>
</div>
```

if button around div then how return the 1252 ????????

Comment: alert($(this).parent().parent().find('a.comments_number').text());

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="postContent">
    <div class="postMeta">
            <a class="comentsQty">
            <i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>
            <a class="comments_number" href="">1252</a>
            </a>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="postOverlayBtn">click</a>
    </div> 



 $('.postOverlayBtn').click(function(event) {
         alert($(this).prev().find('a.comments_number').text());
    });
```

Use this function. In your code you missed ');' in end of the function

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/r1xj2gvn/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/r1xj2gvn/6/)         check this link